# Which table is used for authentication in Liferay by default?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

Which table is used for authentication in Liferay by default? And is there any **LDAP** or **Active Directory** used?

Comment: Well,  though question is not clear, user_ table contains encrypted password.  And you can integrate liferay with ldap

Comment: 1st question: Wrong question: You don't want to know. It's an implementation detail and you'll wreak havoc if you ever change it or access it directly. 2nd: Yes, Liferay supports LDAP, and AD with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table called `user_` contains the hashed password, secret question/answer and other information contained within the user model.

It would be wise not to use this table directly but to make use of the Liferay API and Classes such as `UserLocalServiceUtil` to retrieve this information.

There is no LDAP or Active Directory in use by default, but it is an optional feature.